# How to accept variations on XMLSchema's dateTime format

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I need to deserialize an XML file into a class.  I'd like to find the best way to handle DateTime values coming in as `YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss`, but the standard expected is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.

Ideas are make the class property string then deal with it (per case, add properties that access and convert, add DateTime extension methods) or use custom serialization.

Is there a better way I'm missing?  It feels like there could be some sort of configuration on the serializing without writing custom, for example.  Just trying to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I had the same ideas : custom serialization (a bit complex...) or _string_ property with appropriate setter.